# How would I make a Django form with confirming password backwards?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I’m using Django-registration’s one-step workflow. I’m adding a third form field, pw3, so that the user must confirm his/her password by typing it backwards. How would I go about that?

Comment: It is probably very bad idea to force user type his/her password backwards

Comment: Err what would be the security concern?

Comment: not a security issue, but related to user experience

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly in django-forms and I don't see any your code example, despite this I hope it's gonna help you.

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    ... # your rest of fields
    password = forms.CharField(label='Enter password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_confirm = forms.CharField(label='Confirm your password from the back', widget=forms.PasswordInput)


    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        password_confirm = cleaned_data.get('password_confirm')

        if password and password_confirm and password_confirm[::-1] != password:
            self.add_error('password_confirm', "Password confirm doesn't match")
```

Also I recommend you to familiarize with documentation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validation-error